# how to create an adjacency matrix from a G(n,p) graph using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, adjacency-matrix, graphml, graph-modelling-language

I am asking to create an adjacency matrix from a random graph. I really have no idea how to do it, the only way I knew was to build adjacency matrix through graph and vertex.

`def adjacency_matrix(n,p)` The n is number of vertex and the p is the probability of there is an edge between 2 vertex.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [NetworkX package](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html). You can use the function [gnp_random_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph.html) for your purpose. It has the following parameters:

> **n (int)** – The number of nodes.
>   **p (float)** – Probability for edge creation.
>   **seed (integer, random_state, or None (default))** – Indicator of random number generation state. See Randomness.
>   **directed (bool, optional (default=False))** – If True, this function returns a directed graph.

```
import networkx as nx

n = 20
p = 0.3

G = nx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph(n, p)
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]